# visifire X Axis Direction Issue:

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, visifire

I have a visifire customization question.

How do I force the direction of X Axis labels?

How do I make the x axis labels on the graph on the right look more like the ones on the left?
[[image: IMG]http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/crunch.png[/IMG]]

As you can see, there is not enough room to display the graph properly

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting Angle and Rows properties in AxisLabels.

Example:

```
<vc:Chart.AxesX>
    <vc:Axis>
        <vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
            <vc:AxisLabels Rows="2" Angle="0"/>
        </vc:Axis.AxisLabels>
    </vc:Axis>
</vc:Chart.AxesX>
```